# Why are spark jobs running using only one executor?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

Any ideas on why my spark jobs end up being executed only on one machine? I'm using mapping functions over ~250MB (51k lines) of data, and I was expecting to see activity in all nodes, however the spark UI only shows activity on one of the three nodes of my cluster. The script I'm using to call my application looks like:

```
spark-submit \
--class sparkUtils.DistributedParse \
--master spark://ip-172-31-27-55:7077 \
--executor-memory 4G \
bin/DistributedParse.jar \
<parameters>
```

I've tried using the `--deploy-mode cluster` but the execution fails, and when using `--total-executor-cores 3` flag it doesn't make a difference . However, according to the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/submitting-applications.html), standalone mode should be used in my case, which matches with this description: "A common deployment strategy is to submit your application from a gateway machine that is physically co-located with your worker machines (e.g. Master node in a standalone EC2 cluster). In this setup, client mode is appropriate."

My Java code looks something like:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DistributedParse");
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);     

/* read and parse custom-delimited multiline text file */
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "WARC/1.0");

JavaRDD<Text> records = context.newAPIHadoopFile(args[0], TextInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, conf).values();

final int urlPosition = 47;
...
ArrayList<String> importedNames = fillFromFile("./names.txt");

final Broadcast<ArrayList<String>> names = context.broadcast(importedNames);

records.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, String>() {

    @Override
    public Iterable<scala.Tuple2<String,String>> call(final String record) {

        ArrayList<Tuple2<String,String>> url_nameEdge = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String,String>>();

        for(String name: names.value()){
            if( record.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase()) )
                url_nameEdge.add(  new Tuple2<String,String>( record.substring(urlPosition, record.indexOf(" ", urlPosition+1)) , name )  );
        }

        return url_nameEdge;
    }
}).saveAsTextFile(outputFolder);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that my problem comes from the singleLineRecords RDD, which is defined using a custom Hadoop file format for parsing a multiline delimited file. By setting up `conf.set("mapred.max.split.size", "10000000");` on the Hadoop configuration to something close to 10MB now I have 18 tasks, running 6 on each of my workers!